# Python 3.7 Docker images

Tags: python, docker

I want to dockerize my python app.  I went to Docker hub and discovered that there are a variety of likely-sounding base images.

```
3.7.0-stretch, 3.7-stretch, 3-stretch, stretch (3.7/stretch/Dockerfile)
3.7.0-slim-stretch, 3.7-slim-stretch, 3-slim-stretch, slim-stretch, 3.7.0-slim, 3.7-slim, 3-slim, slim (3.7/stretch/slim/Dockerfile)
3.7.0-alpine3.8, 3.7-alpine3.8, 3-alpine3.8, alpine3.8, 3.7.0-alpine, 3.7-alpine, 3-alpine, alpine (3.7/alpine3.8/Dockerfile)
3.7.0-alpine3.7, 3.7-alpine3.7, 3-alpine3.7, alpine3.7 (3.7/alpine3.7/Dockerfile)
```

Despite my attempts at a Google search, I couldn't figure out the differeces between "stretch", "slim", "slim-stretch", and alpine.  Help?

Comment: `stretch` we can argue about, but the others are clearly described on that very page: https://hub.docker.com/_/python/

Comment: Whoops, I missed that at the bottom of the page.
But, still leaves some open questions:  1) what is stretch? 2) the bottom text suggests using plain 3.7.n images, but I don't see them in the detailed listing of all available images.  What am I missing?

Comment: I think that all those "stretch" tags come from Debian's codename "Stretch": https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch

Comment: In any event, 3.7 clearly does exist and looks like the version I want.  This mostly reduces down to my bad for misreading the page. Sorry all.

Comment: Fixed :) https://github.com/docker-library/docs/pull/1332

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Github repo with Dockerfiles is here, but it's very dynamic and not easily readable:

https://github.com/docker-library/python

The readme is also located here:

https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/python

Looks like info about `stretch` is really missing. Could not find even in git revision history if it was accidentally removed.

I have created an issue: https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/343

*Stretch* is a codename for Debian 9 - currently the stable version (until  2019-07-06, when Debian 10 *Buster* was released). The "oldstable" Debian 8 has codename *Jessie*.

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases

My personal recommendation is to use the minimalistic Alpine images and fallback to the Debian ones if something doesn't work :)

Comparison of Debian vs. Alpine (from the Docker point of view if possible):

- https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/alpine-vs-debian
- https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/the-3-biggest-wins-when-using-alpine-as-a-base-docker-image

From my limited experience the most notable difference is `apt` vs. `apk` and GNU libc6 vs. musl libc. And Alpine uses [busybox](https://busybox.net/about.html) instead of the full versions of many system commands.

Update: Many Python wheels with compiled binary code will work with Debian-based images, but have to be recompiled (by `pip install`) for Alpine-based images. In these cases I recommend to use the Debian-based images.

Comment: so if im doing FROM python:3.7   am i using ubuntu? alpine? which OS?

Comment: @Mr-Programs on https://hub.docker.com/_/python you see that `3.7` is a "shared tag" with `3.7.3-stretch` and `3.7.3-windowsservercore-1809` (and 2 others windowsservercore). So in Docker on Linux `python:3.7` would use `3.7.3-stretch` - that's Debian current stable version (it has codename "Stretch").

Comment: As of July 2019 the stable Debian version is Debian 10 codename "buster". Therefore the best choice in terms of compatibility and stability is `python:3.7-buster`. For Python 3.8 there only is a buster image, but not a stretch image anymore.

Comment: TWTMC: For users using Machine Learning/Data Science libraries some of the main packages (SciPy and Scikit-Learn) can present some problems using the alpine images. Sometimes it's necessary to go to the version images to avoid some errors due to the missing libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Please notice that at the bottom of the Python Oficial Docker Hub you'll get good clues about whats in the repo.

Stretch, Apline, Buster are referring to the **base OS** the container uses.

[Stretch and Buster](https://www.zdnet.com/article/debian-gnulinux-jessie-is-out-stretch-is-in-buster-is-started/#:%7E:text=Debian%209.0%20Stretch%20is%20now,the%20near%20future%20as%20well.) are consecutive versions of Debian, while [Alpine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux) is a minimalistic version for Linux based on musl and BusyBox.

The **difference in size** is considerable, going up to 30x from Alpine to others, but **trade-offs** are to be taken in account as a better-community to better-size-performance kind.

Also, take in account what your container will need to have installed and how minimalistic it can get.