# What is difference between alpine, alpine-jre and alpine-slim docker base images?

Tags: dockerfile

I want to add a docker base image to my dockerFile. I am a little confused between these three types of images. I am trying to get a base image for Java8 openjdk

Comment: You might want to check out this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954187/docker-images-types-slim-vs-slim-stretch-vs-stretch-vs-alpine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker images - types. Slim vs slim-stretch vs stretch vs alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954187/docker-images-types-slim-vs-slim-stretch-vs-stretch-vs-alpine)