# Purpose of AdoptOpenJDK jdk-slim vs jre?

Tags: java, docker-image, adoptopenjdk

I wonder what is the use case for `jdk-slim` docker image?

In which cases should I use `jdk-slim` instead of `jre`?

Are there any well-known issues (e.g. some monitoring tools are not working on `jre`?)

Comment: here asked before, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954187/docker-images-types-slim-vs-slim-stretch-vs-stretch-vs-alpine

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK answers provided there do not answer in which cases I should consider `slim` over `jre`

Comment: you right, i missed jre,

Comment: BTW i saw there is jre-slim images on the docker hub, could be on same purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jdk` - stand for Java Development Kit, so it includes development tools (e.g. javac)

`jre` - Java Runtime Environment (no Javac, for instance).

`slim` - This image installs the `-headless` package of OpenJDK and so is missing many of the UI-related Java libraries and some common packages contained in the default tag

Do you need to build something with your image? => `jdk` or `jdk-slim`.

Do you need just to run already build app? => `jre` or `jre-slim`

P.S. It's too late for the author. Hopefully, it will be useful for somebody else.